# How do I set AllowOverride All? I've tried EVERYTHING but not avail

Tags: apache-2.2

Guys, really, I know this is a super newbie question, but I've done all of my homework. I've googled it and duckduckgo'd it, but to no avail.

How can I set AllowOverride All? Whenever I do this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/domain.com/public_html">
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

It does not work! :\

Comment: Technically, if you tried *everything* you'd have found a solution...

Comment: Technically, yes. In this case it was to emphasize out my efforts

Answer (score 3):

Have you changed the [AccessFileName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#accessfilename) directive?

Are the permissions for your .htaccess files set such that Apache can read the files?

Are you restarting Apache between changes to the [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive?

Comment: Yes to all. I found the problem was that my installation of the script that I was installing did transfer over its .htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong (I'm fairly new to this too), but don't you need:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Right below AllowOverride All?

```
<Directory "/var/www/domain.com/public_html">
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I just tried that now but it didn't make a difference :\

Comment: And yes, I do have mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: Order and Allow have almost nothing to do with AllowOverride.